# Hiding finder preview panel... forever

Tags: macos, finder, preview

I'm not sure why but quite recently Finder likes to show me the Preview panel on new Finder windows.

I've tried every method I could find:

- Hiding the preview. Close the finder and open a new window. Will show the same preview again.
- Go to `/Users/$username$/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` and edit the `ShowPreviewPane` setting it to `NO`. This will magically revert to `YES` after I relaunch the Finder.

I'm out of ideas. What could I do?

Comment: There is no string `ShowPreviewPane ` in my finder.plist I do see `PreviewPaneVisibility` for each window, but no global control. It may depend on what your default for New Finder Window is set to - or which OS you're on. Need more info.

Comment: I'm on El Capitan, latest version from yesterday (10.11.1)

Answer (score 7):

Finder->View Menu->Hide Preview.

Comment: Already did that and that didn't work.

Comment: And how do you do it system wide. Every time I start Finder have to do it over again.

Answer (score 5):

I tried deleting library/preferences/com.apple.finder.plist but it had no effect.  Neither did changing "Hide Preview" in Finder's View menu.

But -- drum roll please -- with the finder window open showing the preview pane, I used the key combo shift-command-P and the pane disappeared from the open window, AND FROM ALL NEW FINDER WINDOWS I OPENED!

Persistence pays!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Open Finder and close preview pane,
2. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (or select in menu: View->Show view options), select needed options and press "Set as default" button.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had the same issue.  Coda, a text editing app, had a lock on the file.  Once I went into Coda's preferences and released the file to Text Editor, my changes to the com.apple.finder.plist file reset.  It's safe to delete the file.  OS X will automatically create a new file shortly after the old file has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal

```
cd /Users/$username$/Library/Preferences/

sudo mv com.apple.finder.plist com.apple.finder.plist.GO.AWAY
```

On the desktop:
Finder->Apple->Force Quit->Relaunch Finder

Check the preview pane (pain) is now gone.

Back to terminal:

```
sudo chmod 444 com.apple.finder.plist
```